# What is the value after the decimal of the zsh time command?

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Update: Based on this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/time/) I confirmed I'm actually using zsh's time command through typing `type time`. However, I still can't find any resource that confirms what zsh's time output means.

I just used the zsh time command and I think it told me my command took 1:08.75.

Am I right to assume that the 1 stands for minutes, the 8 stands for seconds and the .75 mean it was 8 and three quarters of a second?

In case it makes a difference I'm using a Mac.

Here's the full code

```
time git clone https://github.com/expressjs/express.git
Cloning into 'express'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 30279 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 30276
Receiving objects: 100% (30279/30279), 8.60 MiB | 132.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17089/17089), done.
git clone https://github.com/expressjs/express.git  1.17s user 0.95s system 3% cpu 1:08.75 total
```

Comment: @John1024 I just ran that command and I got a blank output. I added the original time command I ran and its full output in case that helps.

Comment: @John1024I realized I was using zsh's time command through oh-my-zsh, but I still can't find any docs to confirm the default format for zsh time commands. Would you happen to know what it is? If not, no worries.

Comment: Yes, `1.17s` means “one second and seventeen hundreds of a second”. If you have doubts about it, note that how this number is displayed obeys the locale (probably `LC_NUMERIC`) and that, for example, you’ll get `1,17s` with a French locale.

Comment: @Maëlan I was asking about the number 1:08.75. I imagine that's the accurate number since cloning the repo definitely took much longer than a second.

Comment: try it yourself: `time sleep 68.75`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running the command in Maëlan's comment and used a timer to verify it ran as expected. The output was in the same format as my question, which confirms that the format is minutes:seconds.fractionalSeconds.